# Is it possible to retrieve/read logs from a file with rsyslog?

Tags: logging, networking, port, syslog, rsyslog

I have a script that allows me to retrieve internet logs. I want to read them using rsyslog (here is my problem) and after reading those logs I want to send them to a virtual machine (this part is ok).
What I have done:

In `/etc/rsyslog.conf` I added the following line:

```
*.*  action(type="omfwd" target="192.0.2.2" port="10514" protocol="tcp")
```

... which allows me to send the logs to the machine `192.0.2.2` on the port `10514`.

So how can I configure rsyslog read the logs from a specific directory?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't read from an entire directory. But you can read from a file using the `imfile` module.

```
module(load="imfile")
input(type="imfile" file="/var/log/file.log")
```

Depending on the logs, you'll need to define a template so rsyslog knows how to read them. If you want to read from multiple files, you'll have to define multiple inputs.

After that, you can add your `omfwd` actions to send the logs to the server. Make sure that you append the forwarding actions **after** the inputs, as rsyslog reads the config from top to bottom.